# How to create long TXT records in DNS through Ansible (longer then 255 characters)?

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-rm

I can successfully create long TXT records (DKIM keys, for example) through the Azure portal, manually.
But it fails when I try it through an Ansible playbook.

```yaml
      azure_rm_dnsrecordset:
        resource_group: "{{ azure.resourcegroup }}"
        zone_name: "{{ azure.dnszone }}"
        record_type: "{{ item.type }}"
        relative_name: "{{ item.name }}"
        records:
          - entry: "{{ item.value }}"
        state: present
      with_items: "{{ azure.creatednsrecords }}"
```

Most records are created successfully, but the long TXT records are failing.

Message: Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: The TXT record's length of 410 exceeds the 255 character limit.

Has anyone seen this happening? And how did you solve it?

Comment: "_Has anyone seen this happening?_", yes, this is quite common. See [TXT records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-zones-records#txt-records). Regarding the mentioned Ansible module, further investigation is necessary. Therefore I can't answer how to solve it. However, you may have a look into [Azure DNS REST API cannot create long TXT records (though the portal can)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues/8249) as a first starting point.

Comment: TXT RDATA values longer than 255 bytes should be presented as multiple values, each of at most 255 bytes long. How exactly depends on the API (if the service is not able to break things down by itself in smaller chunk). As this stage your question does not seem related to programming, and as such might not be on topic here.

Comment: Why would writing Ansible playbooks not be programming?

Comment: @U880D I already found the topic you are mentioning. It does not solve the issue. I tried to split the record into two records as input. But then the azure_rm_dnsrecordset module overwrites the first record with the second, instead of adding it.
I am posting this here, hoping not to be the first one having this issue.

Comment: As already mentioned the module source itself, [azure_rm_dnsrecordset.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure_preview_modules/blob/master/library/azure_rm_dnsrecordset.py) might need further investigation. Since the technology stack is owned by a vendor, it might also be possible to file support request there.